# Software development life cycle for Enterprise Android applications

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, deployment, google-drive-api

I have a question related to the development and deployment of Android application in an Enterprise. Like all other enterprise developments we have development, test, integration, staging and production environments. In order to respect our adopted norms, we have to respect the same process. One precision, that our planned application will be using Google Drive Android SDK. 
Now I am looking for various options which are available to respect the same norms.

We have to release 4 different APKs so in all 4 APKs we will be targeting:

1)  Different Users and groups to access Drive SDK.

2)  Different databases

So I have two questions seeking different recommendations from experience users about this issue.

1)  There exists some sort of environment from Google which can be used for this purpose. Can “Google play services developer console” be used for this purpose?

2)  Or we have to generate APK using batch file which contains commands to uses utilities of android and java like aapt.exe to generate unsigned APK file and jarsigner to sign APK file with a certificate. To distinguish between various environments (development, test, integration, staging and production) we use some sort of PROPERTIES files. Distribution of APK can be done either through Air watch or Google Private market place.

Thanks to all for giving a time and for useful input.